# windows 7 slow (paging a lot) after closing VMware

Tags: windows-7, vmware, paging

I am using Windows 7 with 4GB of memory, and am running VMWare with 2GB of memory.

Every time I shutdown the VM, for some stupid (or overly smart) reasons, there is a lot of paging going on, and I simply can't do anything useful for about 3-5 minutes.
This does not happen on Windows XP, where the memory gets claimed almost instantaneously.

Is there anything I can do to stop the paging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [blog](http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2009/03/fix-vmware-slow-to-release-swapped.html).
This guy had the same problem, and now he has solved it. Give it a try.

Posted by twig at 11:34 AM Sunday, March 1, 2009:

> Ever since upgrading to VMWare v6.5.1, I've noticed it would take
>   several minutes for my laptop to respond to input after closing VMware
>   or pausing/shutting down a guest.
>
> The excessive harddrive activity would halt my host operating system
>   and prevent hibernation from working (causing me to nearly miss my
>   train station several times!)
>
> Luckily, someone's found the solution to fixing this problem by
>   setting some hidden configuration options.
>
> Open up your "guest.vmx" file in Notepad and paste the following lines
>   at the end of the file.
>
> ```
> mainMem.useNamedFile = “FALSE”
> prefvmx.useRecommendedLockedMemSize = “TRUE”
> prefvmx.minVmMemPct = “100″
> ```
>
> This has stopped the excessive harddrive activity on my laptop and I
>   have been able to get off the train on time.

Comment: As I am using VMWare player, this line fixes my problem: prefvmx.minVmMemPct = “100″ . Thanks!